# Re-opening project file, items added from organization portal appear as broken data sources

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

I made a new project file last week that required a number of layers hosted in our organization's portal.  I searched for them in the Catalog under Portal, and dragged the necessary layers from the search results to the ToC.  Everything worked fine.

Today, I re-opened the project file and all the items that were added from Portal are showing up as having broken data sources (with the red exclamation point).  If I click the red ! to repair the data source, I can search for and find the correct layers under Portal, but I can't set the data source to those layers (double-clicking them, or selecting them and clicking "open" results in trying to open as if it's a folder, and there's nothing inside).

I am able to re-add all these layers from Portal, so I know there's nothing wrong with that, but I can't repair the data sources.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are the items you added shared publicly to the Portal? Are you logged in to the Portal before you re-open the project package?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if they're shared publicly or just to our organization.  And yes, I'm signed in to my organizational account before I open the project.